# How do I stop my resize function from causing _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead -> nBlockUse)?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, delete-operator

I've been tasked with implementing a stack **using arrays**  However, when I run the program it says _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead -> nBlockUse). The debugger directed me to the delete statement in the resize function, but I'm unsure how to fix the problem.

Note: I'm trying to do so without using vectors.

```
   void resize(){
       Type* temp = new Type[asz + 2];  // store old values
       for (int i = 0; i < asz; ++i){ temp[i] = arr[i]; }
       delete[asz] arr;             // delete old array
       arr = temp;                  // keep new larger arr
       delete[] temp;
       asz =+2; // array size
       }
```

Comment: In the second loop you go out of bounds for the `temp` array. There's also no need for the temporary array, or even the manual loops (see e.g. [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)). But more importantly, there's no need for the dynamic memory allocations and pointer *at all* when you have [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: More importantly, you don't actually resize `arg` (whatever that is), unless `arg == *this` (I *guess*)

Comment: Just use `std::vector` and your problem goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of changes that may fix your problem. You don't initialise `sz`, your final for-loop was copying according to the new increased size, yet `temp`was only the old size. You also don't appear to set the new `sz` anywhere. Could be any or all of these that cause a memory overwrite invalidating the debug blocks and causing the assertion you have seen.

```
  void resize(Type& arg){
       Type* temp = new Type[arg.sz];   // store old values
       for (int i = 0; i < arg.sz; ++i){ temp[i] = arg[i]; }
       int oldSz = arg.sz, newSz=arg.sz + 2;
       delete[] arg;                // delete old array
       arg = new Type[newSz];          // create new larger arr
       arg.sz = newSz;
       for (int i = 0; i < oldSz; ++i){ arg[i] = temp[i]; } //copy back
       delete[] temp;
       }
```

Comment: It turned out the problem was with my initialization/constructor.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.